# Why is Postgresql using filter instead of index?

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I have my postgresql `ad_item` table with the following columns.

```
id | name | remaining | created_at
```

And then I have my index on remaining which are less than or equal to 300.

```
create index remaining_index on ad_item using btree(id) where remaining <= 300
```

But when I do `explain analyze` on my query.

```
explain analyze select id from ad_item where remaining <= 300
```

It is showing me the following.

```
Seq Scan on ad_item  (cost=0.00..2.06 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.010..0.013 rows=1 loops=1)
  Filter: (remaining <= '300'::numeric)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 4
Planning time: 0.115 ms
Execution time: 0.026 ms
```

Why is it not using my `remaining_index`? Is that index redundant?

Thanks.

Comment: Because your table is too small (only 5 rows) to make the index usage efficient.

Comment: You can execute `set enable_seqscan=off` before the query to make sure it can use your index :)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, hi, awesome. so i believe as i get more rows, it will start to use index and then will be faster? thanks.

Comment: If the index is not very selective (i.e. if most of the rows match your `remaining <= '300'` condition) it may not be used at all, even your table has a large number of rows.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make a very apx calculations to get the idea when it starts using your index.

```
t=# drop table s07;
DROP TABLE
t=# create table s07 (i int, r int, t text);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into s07 select 1,1,'some text';
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into s07 select 2,2,'some text';
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into s07 select 3,3,'some text';
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into s07 select 4,4,'some text';
INSERT 0 1
t=# create index s07i on s07 (i);
CREATE INDEX
t=# analyze s07;
ANALYZE
t=# SELECT relname, relkind, reltuples, relpages FROM pg_class WHERE relname LIKE 's07%';
 relname | relkind | reltuples | relpages
---------+---------+-----------+----------
 s07     | r       |         4 |        1
 s07i    | i       |         4 |        2
(2 rows)
```

despite the fact that index has same amount of rows and less columns, on small amount of data it actually takes twice more space! relation -1 page, index -2, so planner performs seq scan:

```
t=# explain analyze select i from s07 where i < 4;
                                         QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on s07  (cost=0.00..1.05 rows=4 width=4) (actual time=0.003..0.004 rows=3 loops=1)
   Filter: (i < 4)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 1
 Planning time: 0.086 ms
 Execution time: 0.013 ms
(5 rows)
```

So after populating some data:

```
t=# insert into s07 select i,i,'some text' from generate_series(1,99,1) i;
INSERT 0 99
t=# analyze s07;
ANALYZE
t=# SELECT relname, relkind, reltuples, relpages FROM pg_class WHERE relname LIKE 's07%';
 relname | relkind | reltuples | relpages
---------+---------+-----------+----------
 s07     | r       |       103 |        1
 s07i    | i       |       103 |        2
(2 rows)

t=# explain analyze select i from s07 where i < 4;
                                         QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on s07  (cost=0.00..2.29 rows=7 width=4) (actual time=0.008..0.016 rows=6 loops=1)
   Filter: (i < 4)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 97
 Planning time: 0.119 ms
 Execution time: 0.029 ms
(5 rows)
```

same picture. so putting even more data:

```
t=# insert into s07 select i,i,'some text' from generate_series(1,299,1) i;
INSERT 0 299
t=# analyze s07;
ANALYZE
t=# SELECT relname, relkind, reltuples, relpages FROM pg_class WHERE relname LIKE 's07%';
 relname | relkind | reltuples | relpages
---------+---------+-----------+----------
 s07     | r       |       402 |        3
 s07i    | i       |       402 |        2
(2 rows)

t=# explain analyze select i from s07 where i < 4;
                                                 QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on s07  (cost=4.22..7.33 rows=9 width=4) (actual time=0.005..0.007 rows=9 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (i < 4)
   Heap Blocks: exact=1
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on s07i  (cost=0.00..4.21 rows=9 width=0) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=9 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (i < 4)
 Planning time: 0.099 ms
 Execution time: 0.017 ms
(7 rows)
```

With conditional index such calculation would be more sophisticated of course, but basically here you can see, that even 100 rows are cheaper to filter from one page, then loading two pages.

Now of course you can [change this behavior with config](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/runtime-config-query.html), eg when we had 100 rows, if you run:

```
t=# set cpu_tuple_cost to 1;
SET
t=# set cpu_index_tuple_cost to 0.000001;
SET
t=# explain analyze select i from s07 where i < 4;
                                                   QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Only Scan using s07i on s07  (cost=0.14..15.16 rows=7 width=4) (actual time=0.012..0.014 rows=6 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (i < 4)
   Heap Fetches: 6
 Planning time: 0.058 ms
 Execution time: 0.028 ms
(5 rows)
```

though the number of pages is for Seq scan:

```
t=# SELECT relname, relkind, reltuples, relpages FROM pg_class WHERE relname LIKE 's07%';
 relname | relkind | reltuples | relpages
---------+---------+-----------+----------
 s07     | r       |       103 |        1
 s07i    | i       |       103 |        2
(2 rows)
```

And surely you can check execution plan and time with temporarily `set enable_seqscan=off`

### Update

100 rows even mentioned in [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-examine.html) as too small amount for indes scan:

> selecting 1 out of 100 rows will hardly be (a candidate for an index), because the 100 rows
>   probably fit within a single disk page, and there is no plan that can
>   beat sequentially fetching 1 disk page.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the detail explanation.